# Criteria: Subquery com multiplas colunas

Tags: hibernate, nhibernate, criteria

Estou com o problema e não consigo resolver. Como transformar essa consulta em NHibernate Criteria.

```
SELECT  ordid, prodid, qty
FROM item
WHERE (prodid,   qty) IN
                 (SELECT prodid,   qty
                 FROM item
                 WHERE ordid = 365)
```

Grato por ajudar.

Comment: C#? VB.NET? Alguma outra linguagem da plataforma? O que você já tentou?

Comment: Poderia ser em qualquer uma das linguagem. Mas a aplicação é em c#. Obrigado pelo comentário @BrunoCésar